# jqChart: show tooltip along one axis only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jqchart

I'm trying to edit the jqChart plugin so that chart tooltips are displayed while moving the mouse along the X axis.

Here's the scenario: If I have a line chart, I do not want to hover my mouse precisely over the line to get the tooltips containing the data point values. Instead, I'd like to get the tooltips while just moving my mouse sideways along the chart.

Can someone please help me with this?

I think this can also be done if someone out here knows how to grab the data point's values for the chart.

Many thanks in advance to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently we are working on this feature. If you want I can send you a working version. Just send an email to dragan.matek@jqchart.com.